# org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator giving wrong id

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, weblogic

**Getting wrong values from sequence**

In weblogic 11, I have 2 manages severs under 1 cluster. I have created 1 datasource on Admin server and attached to cluster. In hibernate side I am using

```
@XmlTransient
@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)  
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_NAME")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_NAME", sequenceName = "SEQ_NAME")    
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

**Exception:**

> org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener saveWithGeneratedId - generated identifier: 41813, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator
>   org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions - Could not execute JDBC batch update ......bla..bla..java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint

Assumption is only on 2nd managed server I am facing this problem.
Can anyone suggest me please.

Comment: i have added the allocationSize=1, still i facing the issue for each 100k hits once. please suggest.!

Answer (score 1):

This might have nothing to do with the server configuration(Cluster etc).

You need to use the allocationSize option.

@SequenceGenerator(name = "productprice_productpriceid_seq", sequenceName = "productprice_productpriceid_seq", allocationSize=1)

Refer below for more details.

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=992448